# Adapters and Loaders for complex data set in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am finding it difficult how to implement adapters or loaders to efficiently load data from an SQL database and showing it into an application.

I store accounts and users in a SQLite database:

- An account has its own data like the name, the payment information, dates, etc
- Users have their name, picture filename, and some other information.
- Data is accessed via a ContentProvider that exposes account and user elements.

I would like to retrieve the list of accounts from the database, and display them using a custom layout that should contain the users of each. Each user has its own layout (basically a picto).

My problem is that I don't know how to structure the adapters and loaders so that each account displays the dynamic amount of users (some may have one, some three, five... etc).

- The application has a listener service that receives network connections and creates, deletes and modifies users depending on the command it receives.

So, would it be possible to implement this structure in such a way that data is loaded in the background and displayed without interfering with the UI? Also, it would be phenomenal if every time the underlying data is modifed the UI reflects this (modifying, creating or deleting an user from an account, etc)

In my head this sounds like nesting two adapters but I don't know if this is possible or I am missing something.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's not depending on Designing of Adapters/Loaders. It's completely depending on your DB design.I mean creating and saving data into your tables and DB

Comment: @Raju-san Thanks for the reply but I don't understand your comment: I correctly create the database and populate it. I can also retrieve the elements via the content provider, but my question is regarding what schema should I use to represent them on screen without clogging the UI according to what I have described in my question.

Comment: I mean to say.If you know the exactly UI with what values you need to display,depending on that you can design your DB and no need to populate multiple quires to retrieve data and it will save system time also.

Comment: Hope [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359654/important-database-designing-rules-which-I-fo) will helps you